# Angular2 custom form control including textfield and error message

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I would like to write custom form control including a textfield and a error message tooltip, which works with model-driven form.

At RC5, the code like following probably worked fine, but at 2.0, it doesn't.
https://embed.plnkr.co/bvFbsf5q74j7eHWuh5y7/

Is there a way to establish relationship with host formControl and child ngModel,
or to access host formControl from inner?

Otherwise, is there a way to realize the idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way.

Finally, my code becomes like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `
  <input type="text" [required]="required" [(ngModel)]="value" #model="ngModel"/>
  <div>inner ngModel errors: {{model.errors|json}}</div>
  <div>ngControl errors: {{ngControl.errors|json}}</div>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInput),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    private innerValue: any = '';
    private ngControl: NgControl;

    @Input() required: boolean;

    private onTouchedCallback = () => {};
    private onChangeCallback = (_: any) => {};

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    }

    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    };

    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    onBlur() { this.onTouchedCallback() }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.onChangeCallback = fn }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.onTouchedCallback = fn }
}
```

The host ngControl can be got from injector, like `injector.get(NgControl)`.
And ngControl has `errors` object I want.